# LiveData - Why is onChanged not called when i postValue?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, coroutine

I am developing an Android application using Kotlin, Coroutine, LiveData.
When I navigate to another fragment, for example, navigate to the second tab of the bottom navigation view and return back to the previous fragment, the `onChanged` method of `Observer` is never called.

**Edit**
I found the problem.
Problems arise when I hold a instance of a view like velow:\

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, container, false)
        }
        return rootView
    }
```

But when I do not keep it, there is a problem, like this:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, container, false)
```

SearchVM:

```
class SearchVM @Inject constructor(
    private val docksRepository: DocksRepository,
    app: Application
) : AndroidViewModel(app) {
    val docks: LiveData<List<Dock>> = MutableLiveData()

    val dockStart: LiveData<Dock> = MutableLiveData()
    val dockEnd: LiveData<Dock> = MutableLiveData()
    val dateStart: LiveData<Calendar> = MutableLiveData()
    val dateEnd: LiveData<Calendar> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch(IO) {
            try {
                val response = docksRepository.getDocks()
                docks as MutableLiveData<List<Dock>>
                docks.postValue(response)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }

    fun setDockStart(dock: Dock) {
        dockStart as MutableLiveData<Dock>
        dockStart.postValue(dock)
    }

    fun setDockEnd(dock: Dock) {
        dockEnd as MutableLiveData<Dock>
        dockEnd.postValue(dock)
    }

    fun setDateStart(calendar: Calendar) {
        dateStart as MutableLiveData<Calendar>
        dateStart.postValue(calendar)
    }

    fun setDateEnd(calendar: Calendar) {
        dateEnd as MutableLiveData<Calendar>
        dateEnd.postValue(calendar)
    }
}
```

BaseFragment:

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
abstract class BaseFragment<T : AndroidViewModel>(
    @LayoutRes private val layoutRes: Int,
    private val viewModel: Class<T>
) : DaggerFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
    var rootView: View? = null
    lateinit var vm: T

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if (rootView == null) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(layoutRes, container, false)
        }
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        vm = ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity(), viewModelFactory)[viewModel]
    }

    protected fun hideBottomNavigationView() {
        (activity as MainActivity).hideBottomNav()
    }

    protected fun showBottomNavigationView() {
        (activity as MainActivity).showBottomNav()
    }
```

SearchFragment:

```
  
class SearchFragment : BaseFragment<SearchVM>(R.layout.fragment_serach, SearchVM::class.java) {

    private val now = Calendar.getInstance()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        Picasso.get().load("https://imgurl.ir/uploads/t326248_.png").into(img_background)

        vm.dateStart.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            tv_startTime.text = it.getDisplayText()
        })
        vm.dateEnd.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            tv_endTime.text = it.getDisplayText()
        })

        vm.dockStart.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            tv_source.text = it.name
        })
        vm.dockEnd.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            tv_destination.text = it.name
        })

        tv_source.setOnClickListener {
            vm.docks.value?.let {
                showDockPickerDialog(it, vm::setDockStart)
            }
        }

        tv_destination.setOnClickListener {
            vm.docks.value?.let {
                showDockPickerDialog(it, vm::setDockEnd)
            }
        }

        tv_startTime.setOnClickListener {
            showDatePicker(vm.dateStart.value ?: now, vm::setDateStart)
        }

        tv_endTime.setOnClickListener {
            showDatePicker(vm.dateEnd.value ?: now, vm::setDateEnd)
        }

        imageButton.setOnClickListener {
            val dockStart = vm.dockStart.value
                ?: return@setOnClickListener toast(R.string.search_fragment_validation_error_fill_dock_start)
            val dockEnd = vm.dockEnd.value
                ?: return@setOnClickListener toast(R.string.search_fragment_validation_error_fill_dock_end)
            val dateStart = vm.dateStart.value
                ?: return@setOnClickListener toast(R.string.search_fragment_validation_error_fill_date_start)
            val dateEnd = vm.dateEnd.value
                ?: return@setOnClickListener toast(R.string.search_fragment_validation_error_fill_date_end)
            val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToSearchResultFragment(
                dockStart,
                dockEnd,
                dateStart,
                dateEnd
            )
            view.findNavController()
                .navigate(action)
        }
    }

    private fun showDatePicker(now: Calendar, callBack: (date: Calendar) -> Unit) {
        val datePickers = DatePickerDialog(
            requireContext(),
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view, year, month, dayOfMonth ->
                val selectedDate = Calendar.getInstance()
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, month)
                selectedDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth)
                callBack.invoke(selectedDate)
            },
            now.get(Calendar.YEAR), now.get(Calendar.MONTH), now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        )
        datePickers.show()
    }

    private fun showDockPickerDialog(docks: List<Dock>, callback: (dock: Dock) -> Unit) {
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(requireActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, docks)
        AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
            .setAdapter(adapter) { DialogInterface, i ->
                DialogInterface.dismiss()
                callback.invoke(docks[i])
            }.show()
    }
}
```

ViewModelModule.kt

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    // Bind ViewModels Here ...

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(SearchVM::class)
    internal abstract fun searchVM(viewModel: SearchVM): ViewModel
}

@Target(
    AnnotationTarget.FUNCTION,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_GETTER,
    AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY_SETTER
)
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
internal annotation class ViewModelKey(val value: KClass<out ViewModel>)

class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(
    private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T = viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}

@Module
abstract class ViewModelFactoryModule {
    @Binds
    internal abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: ViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory
}
```

AppComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        ViewModelModule::class,
        ViewModelFactoryModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<App> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

}
```

BaseActivity.kt

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
abstract class BaseActivity<T : AndroidViewModel>(private val viewModel: Class<T>) : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    lateinit var vm: T

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        vm = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory)[viewModel]

    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: A little bit more code about how exactly do you register observers could be helpful. There must be a function that is called inside of which you register observers. When does your code call that function?

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu I will send it to you now
Thank you for your attention and response

Comment: `vm.dateStart.observe` line must be written in some method of a class. It would be helpful to see which method hold that line and what calls this method. If you can post everything that is related to registration of the observer within `BaseFragment` and sub-class fragments that extend from `BaseFragment`. The issue can be in the way you are registering observer.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu The question was edited

Comment: Your code looks fine and should work. When you navigate back to the fragment and then call `setDockEnd` or `setDockStart` does `onChanged` getting called? It is also possible that your fragments' views are not destroyed after the first time they are created and then reused (depend on the bottom navigation implementation). It means that `onViewCreated` is not called for the second time and `onChanged` is also not called because observers already received the latest data.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu They are called.
But the thise ```    vm.dateEnd.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            tv_endTime.text = it.getDisplayText()
        })```method is not called.

Comment: @JeneaVranceanu i know what is the problem but i don't know how to resolve thiat.
I explained it in detail in the question itself.